# Change State while hovering Button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I´m at a bit of a loss. I´m fairly new at React. I have a background video which is playing through React.Player and I want to change the URL of it (they are local files in the project) while I hover the button.

I managed to change the url with the use of `useState` when I click the button with the `onClick` function. However, `whileHover` is not working for me :/ can someone help me out?

```html
const [text, setText] = useState("videos/planet.mp4")

 return (
    <div
        <div>
            <Button whileHover={() => setText("videos/Transition.mp4")} >
            "testbutton"
            </Button>

        </div>
        
        <motion.div class="react-player.full">
            <ReactPlayer 
                url={text}
                width="120%"
                height="120%"
                playing="true"
                loop="true"
                align="center"
            />
        </motion.div>

    </div>
)
```

That´s not the whole code, just these two important things.

**EDIT**

solved it by adding a `motion.wrapper` around the button.

Comment: Please don't add the answer in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`

```html
const [text, setText] = useState("videos/planet.mp4")

 return (
<div
<div  >
        <Button 
           onMouseEnter={() => setText("videos/Transition.mp4")} 
           onMouseLeave={() => setText("videos/planet.mp4")} >
        "testbutton"
        </Button>

    </div>
    
    <motion.div class="react-player.full"  >
      <ReactPlayer 
       
       
       url={text}
       width="120%"
       height="120%"
       playing="true"
       loop="true"
       align="center"
       
       />
      </motion.div>
  </div>
  )
```

Comment: well I acutally solved it by adding a motion.wrapper around the button. Thus I was able to  change it. I actually only needet it to change and not to go back but thanks anyways! You guys are really fast